# Finite Simple Groups gap recently filled

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The recent paper,
"Aftermath," by
Peter Cameron ([arXiv:1111.4050v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4050)), contains this remark concerning
the classification of the finite simple groups:

> The Classification of Finite Simple Groups [16] is the greatest collaborative effort ever in mathematics, running to about 15000 journal pages. (Ironically, although the theorem was announced in 1980, the proof contained a gap which has only just been filled.)

Can someone explain (at a high level) what was the gap and who filled it?
(Cameron gives no reference.)  Thanks!

Comment: I believe it may be a reference to the classification of [quasi-thin groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasithin_group), filled by Aschbacher and Smith around 2004.

Comment: Thank you, Arturo!  After reading a bit on quasithin groups, I see that you are surely correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering as a CW so the question will not appear as unanswered.

I believe it may be a reference to the classification of [quasithin groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasithin_group); this was filled by Aschbacher and Smith in a series of papers around 2004.

The fact that this was a gap that needed to be filled only became apparent as the proof was being organized for re-publication (in the [AMS book series](http://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/bookstore/booksearch?pg1=&s1=&op1=AND&co1=AND&pg2=&s2=&op2=AND&co2=AND&pg3=AUTH&op3=AND&s3=&co3=AND&pg4=ATTL&op4=AND&s4=Classification+of+finite+simple+groups&co4=AND&pg5=AS&op5=AND&s5=&co5=AND&pg6=CMSC&s6=&op6=or&co6=AND&pg7=%40PYR&arg1=eq&s7=&fn=100&d=BOOK&p=1&u=&r=0&l=100&f=S)).